# How does a cell create/gain its initial ribosomes for protein synthesis?

Tags: proteins, ribosome

I did some quick google searches for how a cellular organism generates or acquires its first ribosomes, but I found nothing. For instance, do the organisms initiating replication form extra Ribosomes to pass on to the created organism?

Comment: @caligari2005 Uhm...why don't you make that an answer and I'll give you the credit for it? :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comment section:

Cells divide and when they do the two daughter cells will not only have copies of the DNA but also of the organelles, the cellular machineries and the cell membrane which implies that yes the daughter cells receive also ribosomes. The replication happens during the interphase.

Comment: I transferred the answer from the comments only 2 days ago so that was actually quite fast :D

Comment: Nevermind then. ;p

Answer (score 2):

Each daughter cell, following mitosis, will contain some ribosomes and DNA transcription machinery already, so it can already synthesise more ribosomes.

In the case of the fertilised ovum, when the organism is only a single cell, the first ribosomes will be those already present in the unfertilised ovum.

So cells never have to start from scratch with no ribosomes.